# не работают файлы настроек сервера

Tags: javascript, php, api

не работают файлы настроек сервера

файлы сервера должны принимать запросы вот такие http://localhost/api/q , но в ответе я вижу исходный код страницы.Может быть файлы сервера не правильные?

на такие запросы он отвечает http://localhost/api/q.php,но мне нужно api реализовать поэтому нужно чтобы отвечал на такие http://localhost/api/q

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

q.php

```
<?php 
$w=23; 
echo $w;
 ?>
```

файл index.php

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://localhost/api/q', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
  //  var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
 var data = request.responseText;

    console.log(data);
  } else {
    // error
  }
};

request.send();
```

Comment: у вас все запросы направляются на `index.php`. Но при этом в `index.php` только код `javascript`. Вы хотите, чтобы `javascript` на сервере выполнился или в чем вообще идея?

Comment: index.php отправляет запросы на q.php,но нужно чтобы q.php принимала в таком видео http://localhost/api/q

Comment: ну хорошо, вот вы зашли на `index.php`. Затем обращаетесь в нем к `http://localhost/api/q`. Такого файла у вас нет и сервер направляет запрос опять на `index.php`.

Comment: `index.php` не направляет. У вас там код javascript, который выполняется в браузере. Напишите, как вы хотите, чтобы к вашему API обращались, и в каком формате возвращать результаты. Сейчас какая-то каша непонятная. Если я правильно понял и `http://localhost/api/q` - это запрос к апи, то в индексе надо эту строку получать в `php`, обрабатывать, запрашивать `q.php` и затем отдавать ответ обратно клиенту.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш файл index.php должен выглядеть так (с понятными упрощениями):

```
// принимаем запрос ЗДЕСЬ
$action = $_REQUEST['q'];

// в зависимости от задачи - получаем данные нужным способом. 
// Например, здесь просто выполняется q.php и выводится содержимое
ob_start();
include $action.'.php';  
$response = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// В нужном формате отправляем ответ
echo $response;
```

Вообще ведь у вас как должно быть:

1. Кто-то обращается **к серверу** `http://localhost/api/q`
2. Вы, **на сервере**, в `htaccess` направляете его запрос на обработчик `index.php`
3. В обработчике пишете **php** код, формируете ответ.
4. Пользователь его принимает.

У вас же в пункте 2 почему-то код, который должен выполняться в браузере. Ваш апи, да и любой, в общем-то, вообще не связан с браузером, javascripta там быть не должно.